# Is it possible to use sql variables in HTML email when using sp_send_dbmail?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, email, sql-server-2012

I am sending an email using sp_send_dbmail on MSSQL server 2012 using HTML format.

This works perfectly however, I want to be able to insert an SQL variable in the HTML email body content. For example, I would expect the code to look as per below however, for some unknown reason, inserting the variable seems to break the HTML code. I suspect that this is happening because when the variable is inserted, all remain HTML tags are automatically closed.

```
DECLARE @email_body1 NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @email_body2 NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @fundraising_link NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @firstname NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @email_leadid INT;
DECLARE @send_email CHAR(5);
DECLARE @email_address NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @segment NVARCHAR(max);
DECLARE @variable VARCHAR(max);
SET @variable = '''Paul''';
SET @email_body1 = 

'

<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
Hello '  + @variable +  ' ....... REST OF BODY CONTENT.
</body></html>

';

SET @email_body2 = @email_body1

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@recipients = 'email@domain.com',
@blind_copy_recipients = 'email@domain.com',
@subject = 'email subject'
@body = @email_body2,
@body_format = 'HTML',
@profile_name = 'HTML EMAIL';
```

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there an easiser way to achieve what I need?

Comment: You aren't concatenating correctly. You should be doing: `'Hello ' + @variable + ' .....'`. Also, you need to close the quote on your `@subject` value.

Comment: Oops... I fixed this however, the problem persists.

Comment: Are you getting an error? If so what is the message? -- Or is it sending, but the HTML is not structured correctly in the delivered email?

Comment: No error, the email is sending HTML which is not structured correctly.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that was received?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET @email_body1 = "Hello <Customer>, Rest of body"
```

Then

```
SET @email_body1 = REPLACE(@email_body1, '<Customer>', @CustomerName)
```

where @CustomerName is NVARCHAR variable with customer name

Note that  tag should be unique, e.g.

Alternative solution (as mentioned in another answer) - just use "+"

Comment: The body message may be prepared by content team, not by developers. When you use tags + REPLACE, dev knows what to put instead of each variable.  If the template looks like "Hello %s, welcome to %s and %s, we would like to promote %s to %s", it may be difficult to read it. Anyway... many problems can be solved by different methods with same or similar efficiency. Just provided alternative solution. From my experience, "tags + replace" works fine.

Comment: You're wrong. REPLACE - Replaces all occurrences of a specified string value with another string value.   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms186862.aspx

Comment: Nicarus, why did you remove and edit messages after I added my comments? That's not cool.

Comment: You remove the message about wrong statement about REPLACE and edit your message about 'FORMATMESSAGE'.  Initially, it was about 'FORMAT'. That's really bad. Did you reduce my reputation or someone else. Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the +, should be something like this

Hello ' + @variable + ' ....... REST OF BODY CONTENT.

Comment: Oops... I fixed this however, the problem persists.